# A closed set in the plane that is pluripolar in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ E $ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. We know that if $E$ is polar, then it is a set of isolated points. Now, suppose $E$ is pluripolar when regarded as $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}\subset \mathbb{C}^{2}$, i.e., there is a plurisubharmonic function on an open neighborhood of $E$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ that is not identically $-\infty$, but on $E$ it is equal to $-\infty$. Can we still say that $E$ is a set of isolated points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero sets of non-constant holomorphic functions $f$ are pluripolar (because $\log |f|$ is plurisubharmonic), so the example $f(z,w) = w$ shows that the (complex one-dimensional) $z$-plane is a pluripolar set in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (viewed as the complex two-dimensional $(z,w)$-space.)

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get it. But the $z-$plane does not turn $\log|f|$ into $-\infty$...

Comment: @M.Rahmat: $\log |f|$ is $-\infty$ exactly at the zeros of $f$, which in this case is given by the equation $w=0$, i.e., the $z$-plane.

Comment: Now i got it! Thanks